# Vectorizing outer and inner loop when these contain calculations and deletes

Tags: python, numpy

I've been checking out how to vectorize an outer and inner `for` loop. These have some calculations and also a delete inside them - that seems to make it much less straight forward.

How would this be vectorized best?

```
import numpy as np

flattenedArray = np.ndarray.tolist(someNumpyArray)

#flattenedArray is a python list of lists.
c = flattenedArray[:]
for a in range (len(flattenedArray)):
    for b in range(a+1, len(flattenedArray)):
        if a == b:
            continue
        i0 = flattenedArray[a][0]
        j0 = flattenedArray[a][1]
        z0 = flattenedArray[a][2]
        i1 = flattenedArray[b][0]
        i2 = flattenedArray[b][1]
        z1 = flattenedArray[b][2]

        if ((np.square(z0-z1)) <= (np.square(i0-i1) + (np.square(j0-j2)))):
            if (np.square(i0-i1) + (np.square(j0-j1))) <= (np.square(z0+z1)):
                        c.remove(flattenedArray[b])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectorizing the inner loop isn't much of a problem if you work with a mask:

```
import numpy as np

# I'm using a random array
flattenedArray = np.random.randint(0, 100, (10, 3))
mask = np.zeros(flattenedArray.shape[0], bool)

for idx, row in enumerate(flattenedArray):
    # Calculate the broadcasted elementwise addition/subtraction of this row 
    # with all following
    added_squared = np.square(row[None, :] + flattenedArray[idx+1:])
    subtracted_squared = np.square(row[None, :] - flattenedArray[idx+1:])
    # Check the conditions
    col1_col2_added = subtracted_squared[:, 0] + subtracted_squared[:, 1]
    cond1 = subtracted_squared[:, 2] <= col1_col2_added
    cond2 = col1_col2_added <= added_squared[:, 2]
    # Update the mask
    mask[idx+1:] |= cond1 & cond2

# Apply the mask 
flattenedArray[mask]
```

If you also want to vectorize the outer loop one has to do it by broadcasting, that however will use a lot of memory `O(n**2)` instead of `O(n)`. Given that the critical inner loop is already vectorized there won't be a lot of speedup by vectorizing the outer loop.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'm sorry but I realized I made a mistake with those two formulas.  I've tried playing around with what you did but can't quite get it.  I modified the two formulas in my original post.  Would you mind checking it out again?

Comment: @user1812626 I think it's correct now, please have a look :)

Answer (score 1):

@MSeifert is, of course, as so often right. So the following full vectorisation is only to show "how it's done"

```
import numpy as np

N = 4
data = np.random.random((N, 3))

# vectorised code
j, i = np.tril_indices(N, -1) # chose tril over triu to have contiguous columns
                              # useful later
sqsum = np.square(data[i,0]-data[j,0]) + np.square(data[i,1]-data[j,1])
cond = np.square(data[i, 2] + data[j, 2]) >= sqsum
cond &= np.square(data[i, 2] - data[j, 2]) <= sqsum
# because equal 'b's are grouped together we can use reduceat:
cond = np.r_[False, np.logical_or.reduceat(
    cond, np.add.accumulate(np.arange(N-1)))]
left = data[~cond, :]


# original code (modified to make it run)
flattenedArray = np.ndarray.tolist(data)

#flattenedArray is a python list of lists.
c = flattenedArray[:]
for a in range (len(flattenedArray)):
    for b in range(a+1, len(flattenedArray)):
        if a == b:
            continue
        i0 = flattenedArray[a][0]
        j0 = flattenedArray[a][1]
        z0 = flattenedArray[a][2]
        i1 = flattenedArray[b][0]
        j1 = flattenedArray[b][1]
        z1 = flattenedArray[b][2]

        if ((np.square(z0-z1)) <= (np.square(i0-i1) + (np.square(j0-j1)))):
            if (np.square(i0-i1) + (np.square(j0-j1))) <= (np.square(z0+z1)):
                try:
                        c.remove(flattenedArray[b])
                except:
                        pass

# check they are the same
print(np.alltrue(c == left))
```

Comment: That's clever (+1)! But now I have to find out why this is soo much faster on small arrays while being a lot slower on large ones. :-)

Comment: Beats me. Could it be the cost of fancy indexing? Or the usual too large arrays are inefficient? Why it's faster for small, no idea.